# how to value is assign to reference variable in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

```
<ng-container  *ngFor="let item of users">
                        <td  *ngIf="item.method == update.business_type">{{item.id}}</td>
</ng-container>
```

how to item.id value is assign to refernce variable.I tried but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create the ***ngLet** or ***ngFor** directive by following reference link:

https://medium.com/@AustinMatherne/angular-let-directive-a168d4248138

This is the way I declare the variables into templates after creating the directives:

```
<ng-container  *ngFor="let item of users">
    <ng-container *ngLet="item.id as ref_var">
        <td  *ngIf="item.method == update.business_type">{{ref_var}}</td>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

This is also possible using *ngVar directive:

```
<ng-container  *ngFor="let item of users">
    <ng-container *ngVar="item.id as ref_var">
        <td  *ngIf="item.method == update.business_type">{{ref_var}}</td>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: (ref_var) value  i want to access outside ng-container its possible